# Reading and print data - colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

kindly assist I am trying to print the result and when I run the code nothing is printed.

```
#read the tweets stored in the file
    tweets_data_path='tweet.txt'
    tweets_data=[]
    tweets_file=open(tweets_data_path,"r")
    #read in tweets and store on list
    for line in tweets_file:
      tweet=json.loads(line)
      tweets_data.append(tweet)
      tweets_file.close() 
      print(tweets_data[0])
```

I have tried to change the indentation for the last line but I received the following error

```
#read the tweets stored in the file
tweets_data_path='tweet.txt'
tweets_data=[]
tweets_file=open(tweets_data_path,"r")
#read in tweets and store on list
for line in tweets_file:
  tweet=json.loads(line)
  tweets_data.append(tweet)
  tweets_file.close() 
print(tweets_data[0])


IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-f5407f1436ea> in <module>()
      8   tweets_data.append(tweet)
      9   tweets_file.close()
---> 10 print(tweets_data[0])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please Advice

Comment: `tweets_file.close()` should have no indentation since you are reading the file line by line. Can you also paste the first 2 or 3 lines of the file `tweet.txt`?

Comment: @ThangM.Pham the file is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is empty, there is nothing to print. Here is my suggestion to avoid the exception due to the empty file:

```
# read the tweets stored in the file
tweets_data_path = 'tweet.txt'
tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")

# read in tweets and store on list
for line in tweets_file:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    tweets_data.append(tweet)

tweets_file.close()

if len(tweets_data) > 0:
    print(tweets_data[0])
```